# Can compilation of several Oracle Pl/SQL package be an atomic operation?

Tags: oracle, plsql, compilation, atomic

If I deploy N pl/sql packages to Oracle DB, can I make their compilation atomic i.e. the changes in these packages will be applied after the successful compilation of all packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since packages are editionable you could look at [edition-based redefintion](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10471/adfns_editions.htm). This would give you a way to atomically switch between versions of your packages.

Answer (score 3):

CREATE OR REPLACE and ALTER PACKAGE are DDL statements, and each single DDL statement is a discrete transaction.  A COMMIT is issued *before* and after each DDL command; that is why there is no rollback for DDL.

It seems to me that you have a configuration management issue.  And configuration management, plus source control, is the way to fix it.  Keep all your PL/SQL scripts (heck , just all your scripts) under version control.  When you deploy a new version of some PL/SQL programs check out the previous versions too (into a separate sub-directory, or whatever makes sense under your deploymenet regime).  Then if there are any problems with the new versions of your packages it is a cinch to re-deploy the old versions.

Comment: True, but the problem is, environments are like hedge funds.  Just because something deployed neatly in Test doesn't guarantee it will do so in production.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers here are good (e.g. edition-based redefinition, which is available in 11gR2).

Another option is provided by [PL/SQL Developer](http://www.allroundautomations.com/), which can be configured to do a test compile (compiles a package to an alternative name) prior to the "real" compile.